# Click tracking code triggers an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I am using an event listener to track clicks on certain links. The links i would like to track are placed over images

I am using the following code and everything works fine on firefox but on chrome the code enters in infinite loop after clicking 3 times on the same page.

```
        function trackComp(event) {


  var clickedElement = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement : e.target;

 
  var elem = clickedElement;
  var ape = [];
  while (elem.tagName != "HTML" && elem.tagName != "IMG") {
    var tuple = {
      "e": elem,
      "pe": elem.style.pointerEvents
    }; 
    ape.push(tuple);
 
    
    elem.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    console.log("cordinates x"+ event.x + "coordinates Y = " + event.y);
    elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.x, event.y);
    console.log(elem);
  } 
  
  // Check if element was found
  
  // Reset the pointer events
  while (ape.length > 0) {
    
    var tuple = ape.pop();
    tuple.e.style.pointerEvents = tuple.pe;
  }
  
}
```

Any ideas on what's wrong with this code ?

thanks

Comment: What does your debugging tell you? You have two loops that have the potential to never end. Which loop is it (presumably the former)? What are the values that are causing it to loop infinitely?

Comment: @jarmod i don't get any error message in the console. i think the infinite loop is coming from this part. once i enter in the inifinite loop, the page just freezes and i have to restart my browser

Comment: Does it repeatedly log "cordinates x ..." messages in the console? Put some kind of hack in like "if I've looped more than 100 times here, log a message or throw up an alert and break out of this loop".

Comment: @jarmod yes it displays coordinates x 235coordinates Y = 570 then loops infinitely. i have added a condition to get out of the loop after 5 iterations. It kind of solves the issue but still trying to figure out the origin of the bug

Comment: Your code calls `document.elementFromPoint()` repeatedly with the same x/y parameters, by the look of it. Wouldn't that just yield the same result every time? I'd guess `elem` is the same value and it's tagName is never HTML or IMG.